# In Vim, how can I save a file to a path stored in a variable?

Tags: vim

This is inside a script:

```
:let s:submission_path = expand("%:p:h") . '\submissions\test_submission.csv'
:echo s:submission_path
:write s:submission_path
```

The script raises an error "can't open file for writing", because I'm on windows and ':' is not a valid filename character. If I name the variable 'submission_path' a file with that name is written (edit: and the contents of the file are as I expect, the contents of the buffer the script is editing).

I don't understand this. The echo command before the write does what I expect it to, output the full path to the file I want to write. But write seems to ignore the variable value and use its name instead? Do I need to dereference it somehow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

vim has very screwy evaluation rules (and you just need to learn them). `write` does not take an expression it takes a string so `s:submission_path` is treated literally for `write`. However `echo` does evaluate its arguments so `s:submission_path` is evaluated.

To do what you want you need to use the `execute` command.

```
exec 'write' s:submission_path
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it. In the end it was easier to write to a relative path, "write ../submission_path/new_submission.csv" but I was truly stumped by this- I guess I could not believe the behaviour would not be consistent.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
:let s:submission_path = expand("%:p:h") . '\submissions\test_submission.csv'
:echo s:submission_path
:execute "write " . s:submission_path
```

Execute will allow you to compose an ex command with string operations and then execute it.

Answer (score 2):

Environment variables don't have this problem, but you have to dereference them like in unix with a dollar sign:

```
:let $submission_path = expand("%:p:h") . '\submissions\test_submission.csv'
:echo $submission_path
:write $submission_path
```

AND it modifies your environment within the vim process, so just be aware of that.

Comment: That's handy too, but I was looking for the way to do it with a local variable- not for a specific reason right now, but to know for the future.